# netbeans: how to disable the automatic text diff?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-6.9

I am using NetBeans for some java projects that are under Subversion scm.
Whenever I editsomething, Netbeans (6.9.1) starts adding colored lines, both in the left and right margins. That, combined with the other colored indicators it adds for like anything I can think of, is driving me insane. I know it's almost christmas but I don't want my editor to reflect that.

How do I disable this diff completely?

How do I completely disable all coloring/hints/... except for syntax coloring of code?

Comment: I got the reversed problem: The diff sidebar not displaying color of changed text at all! It ignores the settings in Tools>Options>Fonts and Color>Diff

Comment: What an annoying feature.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

View -> Uncheck (X) Show diff sidebar

Comment: great! can't believe I didn't look in the view menu.. do you also happen to know how to disable other sidebar features?